# Fetching each records in MySQL table within specific date range

Tags: php, mysql

can anyone suggest me way to display all records in MySQL table within a specific date range, and if no records available on the date, it will still display as NULL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE date IS NULL OR date BETWEEN 'date1' AND 'date2';
```

If you wish to include **date2** with the result, use this

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE date IS NULL OR date BETWEEN 'date1' AND ADDDATE('date2', INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```